# Laravel - file_get_contents() is creating unnecessary uploading file in public folder

Tags: php, laravel, file-get-contents

```
$json_data = file_get_contents(base_path('app/database/fixtures/xyz.json'));
```

Above code is unnecessary copying `xyz.json` in public folder.

How Can I fix this?????

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

try it in laravel

```
$json_data =File::get(storage_path('app/database/fixtures/xyz.json'));
```

Comment: Thanks ... it works for me. 

For Symfony ... what should I use????

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.